# Add admin prefix in usermgmt plugin in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i want make separate admin login but not working giving me error for below url

```
sitename/admin/admin_login
```

**Error:**

```
Error: AdminLoginController could not be found.

Error: Create the class AdminLoginController below in file: app/Controller/AdminLoginController.php
```

**Cake Php routing setting mention below**

app\Plugin\Usermgmt\Config\routes.php

```
Router::connect('/login', array('plugin' => 'usermgmt', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')); // working fine
Router::connect('/admin_login', array('admin' => true, 'plugin' => 'usermgmt', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'admin_login')); // not working
```

app\Config\routes.php

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

app\Plugin\Usermgmt\Controller\UsersController.php(action in controller)

```
public function admin_login() {
// here is admin login code
}
```

**My view file path**
app\Plugin\Usermgmt\View\Users\admin_login.ctp

Answer (score 0):

Your route is set up for `/admin_login`, NOT `/admin/admin_login`, like the URL you say you're trying.

Just change your URL to `sitename/admin_login` and it should work.

Comment: i want to run my url like that for admin login sitename/admin/login or sitename/admin/users/login

Comment: i have used like that sitename/admin_login but giving me error .......... Error: The action admin_admin_login is not defined in controller UsersController

Error: Create UsersController::admin_admin_login() in file: app/Controller/UsersController.php.

Comment: Please alter your question to exactly what you want instead of wasting others' time on examples that aren't actually the problem.  If what you put in your question IS what you want, please re-read my answer.